# Playing a video on SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview

I'm trying to make my app run video, but it doesn't work and I think it's because of the surface attributes.  I don't know what I should put in the surfacechanged brackets, all I know is that I want it's parameters to cover the whole screen except for my button.  I'm uncertain about what to put for the surfaceDestroyed, I just want my video to restart every time it end.  Also the set data source I ponder whether or not I entered in the right code considering that it's much different than the example I found on the internet.

```
public void surfaceChanged (SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {  
 }

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    try {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource("com.vid.vid_n_vid.vid");
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 @Override
      public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //set the surface holder to use in displaying the video
           mPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);
           try {
            //set data source to the video file
                mPlayer.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.andtip/"+R.raw.pixarforbirds));
                //prepare the MediaPlayer
                mPlayer.prepare();
                //start playing the video
                mPlayer.start();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

      }
```

Comment: Hmm it didn't work, but that could be because I'm setting the wrong uri path.  I'm not sure what I would set the uri path to because the whole thing is full of complexity.